# Searching Multiple Elements In XML File

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

I'm using the W3C Live Ajax Search found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp). Their code only searches one element, the "title".  I would like to have it take the user's query and search through multiple elements, for example, the 'title' and the 'url'.

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("live.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
  {
  $d=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
  $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
  if ($d->item(0)->nodeType==1)
    {
    //find a link matching the search text
    if (stristr($d->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q) !=false)   
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint=
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "<br />" . 
        $d->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint . "<br /><br />" .
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "<br />" .  
        $d->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="")
  {
  $response="no suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;

?>
```

Can somebody give me an example of how to make it work?  From what I understand, stristr will only search one haystack and you can't use arrays, so is there another way?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a way:

```
if ( (stristr($d->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q) !=false) || 
     (stristr($z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q) !=false) )
```

I doubt this is the optimal way, so if anybody has a better solution feel free to add it.